# Match query fror comma separated string in sqllite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Which is better way to find particular number from comma separate string in sqlite ?

my datatable

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|id                 |   name                 |  relations(This is String)|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1                  |   ABC                  |  1,2,3,4,5                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|2                  |   XYZ                  |  14,3,4,5                  |  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My goal is to find row which relation contains 1 and delete this relation from string 
but when i use like query it returns me both rows to and rest of things i do in java

I want to find exact rows which have exact match i know it can be done using regexp i dont know how

Comment: try this `select * from table where id IN(1,2,3,4,5)`

Comment: Step 1 : execute this query "SELECT relations FROM table_name" 
step 2 : separate values using "split" function 
Step 3 : execute your delete query

Comment: The best way to handle this is to change the database structure so that you have a second table for the relations, with one value per row.

Comment: Tell your DBA to go back to school.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot search for regex in sqlite database in android. See this [how to search sqlite database using regular expression in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266515/how-to-search-sqlite-database-using-regular-expression-in-android)

But you can search for the regex in the string that is returned:

```
 String RESULT_FROM_DB = "1111,1,3,234,1,2,4";
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b1\\b");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(RESULT_FROM_DB);
 if(m.find()){
     //Do your stuff here. 
     System.out.println(m.start());
     System.out.println(m.end());
 }
```

You should replace `1` in the regex used to compile with the number that you need (Dynamic value as you said.)