# Android contacts storage (sqlite where the contacts are stored) supports REGEXP?

Tags: android, regex, sqlite

I've seen that sqlite by default does not come with REGEXP defined (links: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8244670/2240409) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7266709/2240409)) but I can't find any information about this regarding the android version of sqlite where the contacts are saved.

I've tried this following:

```
final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
                PROJECTION_SEARCH_FOR_CONTACT, 
                "upper(" + Data.DISPLAY_NAME + ") REGEXP \\b " + "123" + "\\b",     
                null,
                null);
```

but I'm getting:

```
05-23 04:28:09.562: W/System.err(24447): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "\" (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, display_name, photo_id, name_raw_contact_id FROM view_contacts WHERE ((1)) AND ((upper(display_name) REGEXP \b  123 \b))
```

As I'm not proeficient with regex, I'm not sure if this is due to Contacts Storage database (SQLite) not having regexp defined or my syntax is wrong.

Can someone clarify me?

Comment: There are two things. firstly I just want to check you didn't want to match the word boundaries around `123` which would be `\b123\b` as you appear to have a space in there. secondly, I think you need to put that regexp in a string so that it can be matched against like so: `REGEXP '\b 123 \b'`

Comment: Thanks for you comment, changing it accordingly to your comment still get the same exception.